# How do you insert some vector elements into another vector that hasn't been initialized?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, insert, mergesort

I like to do this because I want try to code the mergesort algorithm and in order to do this I need to know how to take specific number of elements from an initialized vector and put them into another unitialized vector, here is my attempt so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {7,4,9,10,0,88};
    vector<int> temp;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = temp.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        temp.insert(it, vec[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I tried to insert all elements of `vec` into `temp` but all I get is the error message "Debug Assertion Failed" and I don't know why... Later to do mergesort I like to insert not all elements but just the half. But I hope you can tell me how to insert at all because I have an imagination how I could make mergesort work but to continue I need to know this please :)

Comment: `temp` isn't "uninitialized". It is default initialized. Default initialized vectors are empty.

Comment: `insert()` invalidates all existing iterators. Including your `it` iterator. After the first `insert()`, the `it` iterator is no longer valid. See the linked question for more information and the right approach.

Comment: `temp.insert(it, vec[i])` invalidates `it`

Comment: To insert at the front use `temp.insert(temp.begin(), vec[i])`. That way, the iterator is always valid.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to insert the elements into temp in reverse order? In that case, replace “it” inside the for loop with temp.begin().

Comment: Thank you everyone I got it working by using it = temp.begin()+i+1; right after the insert operation temp.insert(it, vec[i]); .

Comment: @Anonymous1847 I just like to take the half elements of the original vector and insert them all into another vector that is empty :) (got it working now)